# No update after 1st round of interview

Tags: interviewing

After attending the 1st round of interviews for about 45 mins, they told me they will call for the 2nd round in the next week, as they wanted to interview few more candidates.

After the week, when I checked with HR, HR told that I will be updated by next week.

After repeated mails also still the HR replies "Still no updates".

edit: I followed up because I know I did the interview good..

Now almost a month has passed after my first interview.
What should I do now? Should I still continue sending mail to HR regarding the status or let it go?

Update: saw this question after 1000 view questions notification..I still remember ..I had applied to the same company 3months later..when they called for an interview again that time I mentioned I had already done 1st round interview but did you did not reply ..then HR told me that project was closed so they did not call. So now this is a new position and I have to take all interviews from first as a fresh candidate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: What type of job were you applying for and was it entry level?  How did you apply for the position?  Was it: 1) over the internet via a job search tool like Monster, LinkedIn, etc.; 2) directly on their website; or 3) by visit?  I'll point out that internet postings tend to generate dozens if not hundreds of applications from different cities, states, and countries... so the chances are slim to begin with.  Otherwise it's possible they are interviewing dozens if not hundreds of applicants so they underestimated the time frame.

Comment: If you are serious about it give them a call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**NEVER** get your hopes up when job hunting. A company could say you have the job but until you sign the contract, don't assume that you are safe.

Keep applying elsewhere, keep interviewing and just pretend the other company no longer exists unless they contact you.

If HR is replying "still no updates" then they are clearly looking for more people for the job, still interviewing, and therefore they are not happy they have found the right candidate. Or they are putting it off, which also makes you think if the company is worth working for.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than chase, I tend to send them a polite email that wraps it up from your end.

Something like:

> Thank you for allowing me the opportunity to interview at your company.  If you'd like a 2nd interview let me know. If another opportunity comes up in the future please consider me interested.

That will then prompt them to inform you either way, and you will stick in their memory for the future.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to let it go.

They know from your reminders that you're interested and will be in touch if they decide to take it further.

From their reluctance to take the initiative, you should probably assume that they won't be back in touch - it's a shame that they've not been honest enough to just say so directly, but there is nothing you can do about that. Then, if they do get back in touch, that will be a pleasant surprise.

Comment: This. What they have done is rude but there is no benefit to pestering them or being rude back. Especially if you still want the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do. Follow up with weekly emails for the first 2 or 3 weeks. After that depending on how badly you need that particular job you can send an follow up email may be one more time. That's it.

I had employers reach out to me even after a month to see if I am available.

Possible reasons given are:

- They were looking for better candidates
- They put the recruitment process on hold
- The recruiter hiring manager or recruiter went on long leave
- They have a large candidate pool & need to comb through everyone.

As the other answer has said, if they really need you, they would have reached out to you.

Meanwhile keep applying, till you land a job. You only need one job, its a numbers game.

Once you land the job, it feels much better to reply to the companies that ghosted you for a while and then suddenly reaches out to see if you are still available.
At that juncture you can reply something like the following : *"I joined a new company. Lets keep in touch for future opportunities"*

PS : Always be polite on email. Hang in there, you will get a job soon enough